# Is it possible to set dynamic checkbox group options in a Solspace Freeform form?

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I have a form where the checkbox group options I show would ideally be based on details for the logged in user. Is it possible to dynamically set checkbox group or radio group options for a Freeform Form within a Twig template?

Comment: same question here!  did you ever manage to achieve this?